# Cypress async form validation - how to capture (possibly) quick state changes

Tags: cypress

I have some async form validation code that I'd like to put under test using Cypress. The code is pretty simple -

1. on user input, enter async validation UI state (or stay in that state if there are previous validation requests that haven't been responded to)
2. send a request to the server
3. receive a response
4. if there are no pending requests, leave async validation UI state

Step 1 is the part I want to test. Right now, this means checking if some element has been assigned some class -- but the state changes can happen very fast, and most of the time (not always!) Cypress times out waiting for something that has ALREADY happened (in other words, step 4 has already occurred by the time we get around to seeing if step 1 happened).

So the failing test looks like:

```
cy.get("#some-input").type("...");
cy.get("#some-target-element").should("have.class", "class-to-check-for");
```

Usually, by the time Cypress gets to the second line, step 4 has already ran and the test fails. Is there a common pattern I should know about to solve this? I would naturally *prefer* not to have change the code under test.

#### Edit 1:

I'm not certain that I've 100% solved the "race" condition here, but if I use the underlying native elements (discarding the jQuery abstraction), I haven't had a failure yet.

So, changing:

```
cy.get("#some-input").type("...")
```

to:

```
cy.get("#some-input").then(jQueryObj => {
    let nativeElement = jQueryObj[0];
    nativeElement.value = "...";
    nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("input")); // make sure the app knows this element changed
});
```

And then running Cypress' checks for what classes have / haven't been added has been effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can stub the server request that happens during form validation - and slow it down, see `delay` parameter https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Use-delays-for-responses

While the request is delayed, your app's validation UI is showing, you can validate it and then once the request finishes, check if the UI goes away.

Comment: This seems like The Right Approach -- but! Per their docs it doesn't work w/ the Fetch API, which I (neglected to say I) am using.

Comment: Sure, you can replace `fetch` with XHR too, see `window.fetch` recipe https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes#stubbing-and-spying